# How can I figure out what happened while I was away from the game?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I had my iPad closed for about an hour and a half and come back to find a well to do vault low on power good on water but out of food and 10 of my 18 dwellers dead.

How can I figure out what happened? Did I run out of food when I was not actively collecting it? Did an event happen when I was not there? I know the runners get a log of what they have done, is there a similar log for the vault so I can see how I ended up dumping all my caps into reviving my well to do dead vault?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as well, 70% of my people died when I closed my ipad and went out for about 15 mins. From the battery consumption I think the game didnt go into sleep mode, or it prevented the ipad to enter sleep mode, so the vault ran out of resources and dwellers died, etc. It was a vicious cycle trying to get back to normal. It took me two hours to raise the deads and stabilise my vault because the game threw all kind of catastrophes at me when I'm low on everything. Now my main power station still has a "something died in here" debuff that makes people terribly unhappy in that room. I think we need to log a bug to bethesda.

Comment: "Oh a corpse, how pleasant" is another expression for that room. I rezed everyone, why game, why?

Comment: There are definitely some bugs but maybe I should not turn my audio off so it will make me aware of what is going on if it really hasn't shut itself off.

Answer (score 2):

I think in the help section is explained that your vault uses water, food and energy for a short time even after you left the game. So if you left with low stats, this could be the outcome.

Comment: I had full stats, and the shelters survive just fine through out the night let alone an hour and a half :/ I am starting to think it was just actively playing while I had it closed. There does not however seem to be a log of any kind that I can find or anyone else knows of to display vault events.

Answer (score 1):

This will occur if you leave the game with low stats (food, water or electricity). If they go below the line, most of your vault will collapse. For example low on electricity means your food and water production may collapse. This means your dwellers will starve or be to thirsty. They will die, your generator crew will die, you have even lesser electricity and the cycle will go on. This could also happen due to inactivity. I have it too sometimes. I leave the game for 3 hours and come back with red stats. I don't know if it's a bug or if the game just goes on in the background. Sometimes my stats didn't change - even over night.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now certain this is a bug in the app. I've restarted with a fresh vault once on my iPad and twice on my iPhone, and I always run into this problem eventually. Usually it's water and electricity that are very low, but at least once all three resources. The last time it happened was not far into the game; I had double sized resource rooms of the 3 types, all fully staffed and all resources in the green when I closed the game - and killed it through the iOS app manager - and when I opened the game this morning water and electricity had been completely depleted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that your game had a delay in getting into stand-by mode, and you were attacked by Raiders. Raiders do steal a high amount of Food.
**It is the best explanation, since *dwellers can't starve out.***